# Visualizar un proyecto web hecho con VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

**Proyecto vue**

Este proyecto lo hizo otra persona y ahora estoy tratando de ejecutarlo.
Ya instale npm, node y vue asi como tambien npm install para las dependencias del proyecto. Ahora lo que estoy haciendo es tratar de ver el proyecto en el localhost, para ello ejecuto npm run serve desde la terminal pero me encuentro con este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Carpetas y archivos completo del proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado probe con el siguiente comando **npm install -g serve**
y luego **serve -s dist**. En este punto la consola arroja un servidor con los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ingreso a esta direccion pero aun no logro visualizar el proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendrian alguna indicacion para resolver esto?

Comment: Debería ser suficiente con ubicar una consola en la ruta raíz del proyecto y ejecutar la comandos `npm install` y `npm run serve`. Luego puedes visitar la página en el `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Necesitas proveer más información sobre el problema, por favor revisa las secciones de ayuda de la comunidad para saber cómo formular una buena pregunta.

Comment: Hola gracias por sus respuestas. 
El proyecto ya esta creado con (VUE), es un archivo que me compartieron y quiero visualizarlo en el local host pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza hice correr esos comandos pero me arroja este error:

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                          23:23:49

 error

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.js' in 'c:\xampp\htdocs\SENAVE'

ERROR in app
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.js' in 'c:\xampp\htdocs\SENAVE'

webpack compiled with 1 error

Comment: Por lo que dice el error te falta el archivo main.js que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta src de tu proyecto. Te dejo un link a un repo de Vue para que veas mas o menos la estructura de todo lo que debe tener. Fijate que la captura que vos pasas es apenas lo que se encuentra en la carpeta /src/components. https://github.com/agustinguerr4/calendario-fe

Comment: Como decia @AgustinG. parece que falta el archivo main.js. Alguien sabe como resolver este tema?

Comment: @Enmanuel el problema es que te compartieron parte del proyecto aparentemente, deberian compartirte un repositorio completo. Un proyecto entero deberia verse mas o menos como eso que te pase el 31/3

Comment: @AgustinG. muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Acabo de editar mi pregunta sirviendo de algunos detalles adicionales, ahora bien, tu crees que con lo que acabo de actualizar sigues pensando que me compartieron un proyecto incompleto?

Comment: @Enmanuel yo lo que quisiera ver es una captura del contenido que bajaste. A ver si existen todos los archivos en la raiz (supongo que al menos package.json existe porque corre npm install) y la carpeta SRC con su contenido. Si todo esta en su lugar, entonces quisiera ver el contenido de src/main.js

Comment: Hola @AgustinG. acabo de actualizar mi pregunta incluyendo la captura del directorio. Avisame si se observa por favor por que creo que mi pregunta ahora se encuentra en revision.

Comment: Tu pregunta esta cerrada porque le faltaba todo lo que agregaste.. igual, por lo que veo, la carpeta scr no esta.. entonces, donde estan los fuentes?

Comment: Te compartieron un proyecto copiando y pegando cualquier cosa, no? "cursos", "direcciones" "BD" "docs_02"... se me hace que te mandaron un monton de cosas. Con un poco de paciencia yo buscaria ahi adentro una carpeta llamada SRC a ver si en algun lado esta el proyecto, pero en realidad lo que haria si fuera vos es contactarme con la persona que te compartio el proyecto, y pedirle que lo suba a un repo desde donde lo puedas clonar. Linus torvalds se paso años creando git para controlar versiones y que justamente no se compartan los proyectos copiando y pegando carpetas xD

Comment: Pues es eso lo que pasa el proyecto los directorios parecen estar modificados de acuerdo a como le fue mas comodo al programador. De igual forma agradezco la respuesta de todos y por supuesto a ponerme como meta una capacitacion intensa de el framework vue.